# Conditional summation in mathematica

Tags: summation

How to write following conditional sum?

$F(\theta1,\theta2)=\sum_{m1,m2} a^*_{m1}a_{m2} A_{m2,m1}(\theta1) \exp[i(m1-m2)\theta2]$, where $A_{m2,m1}(\theta1)$ is a conditional function, such that

$A_{m2,m1}(\theta1)=\sqrt{\frac{\Gamma(m2+k)\Gamma(m2-k+1)}{\Gamma(m1+k)\Gamma(m1-k+1)}}\frac{1}{\Gamma(m2-m1+1)} {}_2 F_1\left(\begin{matrix}k-m1& &k+m2& \\&m2-m1+1&
\end{matrix};f(\theta1)^2\right)$ for $m2\ge m1$

and

$A_{m1,m2}(\theta1)=(-1)^{(m2-m1)}A_{m2,m1}(\theta1)$ for $m2<m1$.

Comment: Look up `Sum[]` and `Piecewise[]`.

Comment: Your expression does not depend on $\theta_2$: is there a mistake in the formula for $F(\theta_1,\theta_2)$?

Comment: `C` is a protected symbol that you cannot use as a variable name. Better to use lowercase letters for variables.

Comment: it is correted now.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a [multiple dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch) for the function `A`:

```
A[{m2_, m1_} /; m2 >= m1, θ1_] = b[{m2, m1}, θ1];
A[{m2_, m1_} /; m2 < m1, θ1_] = c[{m2, m1}, θ1];
```

With the given hypergeometric functions:

```
A[{m2_, m1_} /; m2 >= m1, θ1_] =
  Hypergeometric2F1[k - m1, k + m2, m2 - m1 + 1, f[θ1]];
A[{m2_, m1_} /; m2 < m1, θ1_] =
  (-1)^(m2 - m1) Hypergeometric2F1[k - m2, k + m1, m1 - m2 + 1, f[θ1]];
```

and then sum them up to a given maximum $m$:

```
F[θ1_, θ2_] = With[{M = 3},
  Sum[Conjugate[a[m1]] a[m2] A[{m2, m1}, θ1] Exp[I (m1 - m2) θ2], {m1, -M, M}, {m2, -M, M}]]
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate it more? For $m2>=m1$ the conditional function is $A_
{m2,m1}(\theta1)=2F^1(k-m1,k+m2,m2-m1+1,f(\theta1))$, with k is a fixed integer (k>=1/2) and $2F^1()$ is a Hypergeometric function. For $m2<m1$,  $A(\theta1)=(-1)^
{(m2-m1) }2F^1(k-m2,k+m1,m1-m2+1,f(\theta1))$.